# How to check command line arugment match? (C)

Tags: c

```
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {

 }
```

In this specific program, I want to check the whether the length of the char **argv is match to the argument count.
However, I am not sure how I can loop through the character array of pointer of pointer.

Can anyone give me a suggestion?
I am very new to C from Java base.

Comment: You might get a response if you explain _**why**_ you want to do this...

Comment: The value in `argc` **is** the length of the `argv` array. That's the contract, you can rely on. What do really want to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: I think this question has answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: @harper Actually, it's my experience that the array has a NULL pointer in the last element, so argc is actually 1 less that the number of elements... This is my experience. It may not be gospel in all implementations.

Comment: @Fe2O3 this is required by standard since, at least, C99.

Comment: @YakovGalka It's been the same since C90.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard is pretty self-explanatory in this case. Relevant parts from C17 5.1.2.2.1:

> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, ...
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by
>   `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the *program parameters*.

You don't need to check if your compiler fulfils the above requirements unless you have reason to believe it is non-conforming, in which case all bets of program behavior are off anyway.